# okhttp to okhttp3 with setSslSocketFactory, setWriteTimeout and setReadTimeout

Tags: spring-boot, okhttp

It's me again,

Someone converted this for me,

```
    OkHttpClient client() {
        if (client != null)
            return client;
        if (System.getenv("trustSelfSignedCert") != null
                && System.getenv("trustSelfSignedCert").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            trustSelfSigned = true;
        if (System.getProperty("trustSelfSignedCert") != null
                && System.getProperty("trustSelfSignedCert").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            trustSelfSigned = true;
        OkHttpClient client0 = new OkHttpClient();
//        if (proxy)
//            client0.setProxy(new Proxy(Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.domain.com", 8080)));
        if (trustSelfSigned) {
            TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }
            } };
            SSLContext ctx = null;
            try {
                ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(tls);
                ctx.init(null, certs, new SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
                client0.setSslSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            }
        }
        client0.setWriteTimeout(timeout * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        client0.setReadTimeout(timeout * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return client = client0;
    }
```

To this,

```
    OkHttpClient client() {
        if (client != null)
            return client;
        if (System.getenv("trustSelfSignedCert") != null
                && System.getenv("trustSelfSignedCert").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            trustSelfSigned = true;
        if (System.getProperty("trustSelfSignedCert") != null
                && System.getProperty("trustSelfSignedCert").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            trustSelfSigned = true;
        SSLContext ctx = null;
        if (trustSelfSigned) {
            TrustManager[] certs = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { 
                    return new X509Certificate[]{}; 
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    if ((certificates != null) && (certificates.length == 1)) {
                        certificates[0].checkValidity();
                    } else {
                        standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certificates, String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    standardTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(certificates, authType);
                }
            } };            
            try {
                ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(tls);
                ctx.init(null, certs, new SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
            } catch (java.security.GeneralSecurityException ex) {
            }
        }        
        if (proxy) {
            Proxy proxY = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxy.domain.com", 8080)); 
            OkHttpClient client0 = new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(proxY)
                    .sslSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory())
                    .writeTimeout(timeout * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(timeout * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
            return client = client0;
        } else {
            OkHttpClient client0 = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory())
                    .writeTimeout(timeout * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(timeout * 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();   
            return client = client0;
        }
        
    }
```

Unfortunately this convertion is wrong when I figured out where is this programming running because before I just want to fix the vulnerability.  The proxy actualy could be done on the jvm parameter, so I just commented this out or you might add it as well to the new code.  Problem are with setSslSocketFactory, setWriteTimeout and setReadTimeout.

If I run the new code, it will have error,

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Hopefully someone will see this code that already fix similar problem.
Thanks again.

Comment: I thought I got the solution on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73072203/local-variable-response-defined-in-an-enclosing-scope-must-be-final-with-okhttp3/73073130#73073130 but it trimmed down the error now to just one java.lang.NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

These need to be commented out, its a bug.

```
private X509TrustManager standardTrustManager = null;
standardTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(certificates, authType);

Then it works!
```