# Local variable response defined in an enclosing scope must be final with okhttp3 Response

Tags: response, okhttp

I have to use the enqueue with okhttp3 Response,

```
    public <R> R getLocation(String url, Function<Reader, R> processor) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        Response response = null;
        client().newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response _response) throws IOException {
                response = _response; \\Local variable response defined in an enclosing scope must be final
            }
                  
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                throw HTTPSError.wrap(e);
            }
        });
        return processor.apply(response.body().charStream());
    }
```

How do I fix this?

If I put variable as the respose.body(), what should be the data type of that?  Jsonbody?

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you put this outside the method,

```
    @Autowired
    Response response;

    public <R> R getLocation(String url, Function<Reader, R> processor) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        client().newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response _response) throws IOException {
                response = _response; 
            }
                  
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                throw HTTPSError.wrap(e);
            }
        });
        return processor.apply(response.body().charStream());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public <R> R getLocation(String url, Function<Reader, R> processor) {
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        Response response = client().newCall(request).execute();
        return processor.apply(response.body().charStream());
    }
```

Comment: Jesse Wilson, that's for okhttp v2 I'm on v3 now.